# Sveltekit Different Builds

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I need different builds for my sveltekit app. I would like to do something like

```
npm run build --option1
```

```
npm run build --option2
```

For option1, I want the following `vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  build: {
    minify: false,
    outDir: "../inst/www",
    sourcemap: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
  //base: "",
});
```

and for option 2:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  build: {
    minify: true,
    outDir: "../inst/www",
    sourcemap: false,
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
  //base: "",
});
```

Thus, `minify: true` and `sourcemap: false`. I was looking for solutions and found a couple but they all seemed rather overcomplicated for such a simple task. So, I am looking for advice of how to best achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use plain arguments you have to jump through a few hoops.
Any arguments are first passed to `npm`, to prevent that you would need to add `--`.
Then the arguments end up being sent to `vite`, which does not know `option1` and would crash, so you need another `--` separator.

So using

```bash
npm run build -- -- --option1
```

would just set an additional argument which you then could read from `process.argv` in the `vite.config.json` and conditionally change the config.

If you just want to switch out the entire config, you could just define two different build scripts that set the appropriate Vite flags in `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build:option1": "vite build -c vite.option1.config.js",
    "build:option2": "vite build -c vite.option2.config.js",
    ...
```

Which then would be executed via

```bash
npm run build:option1
npm run build:option2
```

(You could also combine adding scripts with the first option, of course.)

Aside from that there is also the environment variable option. You could set them with/before the `npm run` and then access the variables in the config via `process.env`. Again, setting the variable could be extracted to named scripts but how this is done is platform dependent (there are helpers like [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to get around that issue).

`cross-env` example:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build:option1": "cross-env BUILD_OPTION=1 vite build",
    "build:option2": "cross-env BUILD_OPTION=2 vite build"
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this great answer! The two different configs approach is completely sufficient for me. Just out of curiosity, is there any particial reason to call the command build:option1 instead of lets say build-option1?

Comment: @JulianKarch: It's a convention that I have observed in a few places (e.g. [Svelte itself](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/3d20b392895b54b75b840fda6511840cc6a7a371/package.json#L7-L16)), not sure if any tooling exists that does something with the format. You could just call it `build-option1` if you want.